# Canadian Temporary Resident Visa fee for passport delivery

Tags: visas, canada, embassies

I've applied for the Canada Temporary Resident Visa online in CIC site and paid the $100 fee.  My application status message in the CIC site shows I need to mail my passport to IRCC.  The [VAC site](https://www.csc-cvac.com/en-US/selfservice/cvac_application_processing) checklist shows I need to make a payment along with my passport. As per my understanding from the VAC site I just need to send below payment (correct me if I'm wrong).

> Passport delivery / e-Application * (Please note that it is not necessary to pay the VAC service charge in addition to this fee.) $32.27

I have a few questions; can someone please answer them?

- With which package do I need to mail this payment: "package one" or "package two"?
- Must the check/bank draft be payable to CSRA Consular Services Inc., and should it be mailed to below address?

> P.O. Box 419557 (CSRA Consular Services Inc)
>   Boston, MA 02241-9557

Answer (score 4):

PACKAGE ONE contains **ONLY** the payment for the *VAC service charge*. Nothing else should be in PACKAGE ONE.

PACKAGE TWO contains your passport, supporting documents, and all other visa application fees, *exclusive* of the VAC service charge.

Answer (score 3):

Below is the Response I've gotten from `ny-info@csc-cvac.com`

Thank you for contacting us. In order to submit your passport for a finalized online application please send the following 6 items to the Visa Application Centre in New York:

[Submitting multiple passports (primary applicant plus spouse/dependent children): You are welcome to mail your passports together, have them sent back together, and combine any fees into one money order. Only one consent form is required, signed by whoever is the primary applicant.]

- VAC Consent Form
- Valid passport listed in your application
- Contact information
- Original letter received from IRCC that instructs you to submit your passport, plus any additional items requested in the letter (e.g. passport photos for PR applicants)
- VAC Service Fee for passport submission – 32.27 USD per applicant. It can be paid:

> At the Visa Application Centre with a credit/debit card (Visa/Mastercard).
>
> By bank draft, cashier’s check, certified check, or money order made out to “CSRA Consular Services, Inc.” We cannot accept personal checks. Tear off and keep the receipt portions of money orders for your records.

Mail-in submissions: Your package must include a photocopy of the completed check/money order you are using to pay the VAC Service Fee – the photocopy will serve as proof of payment, and we cannot continue processing your passport without it. You will submit the actual check/money order for the payment by mail to the following address:

CSRA Consular Services, Inc.
P.O. Box 419557
Boston, MA 02241-9557

DO NOT SEND APPLICATION DOCUMENTS, PASSPORTS, OR OTHER FEES (e.g. APPLICATION FEES) TO THE LOCKBOX

- Return mailing options:

A) Submit a prepaid USPS, UPS, or DHL envelope (must be larger than letter-sized) to our office. Be sure to include a tracking # on it.

B) Submit a fee of 20.21 USD for us to create a FedEx shipment (US addresses ONLY).

This can be can be paid by Visa/Mastercard at the VAC OR by bank draft, cashier’s cheque, certified cheque, or money order directed to “CSRA Consular Services, Inc.” **Please be advised that we can not accept personal checks or cash.** You must include a photocopy of the check or money order when you send your passport, as well as the name, address, and phone number you would like on shipping the label. The original cheque(s) must be sent to the following lockbox with your name written on the back with a pencil:

CSRA Consular Services, Inc.
P.O. Box 419557
Boston, MA 02241-9557

DO NOT SEND APPLICATION DOCUMENTS, PASSPORTS, OR OTHER FEES (e.g. APPLICATION FEES) TO THE LOCKBOX

Processing time for passports may be anything up to 10 business days. If your travel is related to an unforeseeable emergency situation please let us know so we can discuss your options. Please let us know if you have any questions.

Visa Application Centre address:

290 Madison Avenue, 2nd Floor

New York, NY 10017

Answer (score 1):

Submit your passport by courier to the Visa Application Centre (VAC) in New York.

Things to include:

1. Valid Passport
2. Passport Request Letter
3. [Consent Form](https://www.vfsglobal.ca/Canada/USA/pdf/USA.doc.pdf)
4. Contact info page with Email, Phone, Full Address
5. 19.90 USD money order - to the order of - 'TT Visa Services Inc'
6. Paid envelop for return Passport shipping from USPS or UPS